# How to access Google CloudML REST API from NodeJS application running in appengine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-authentication, google-cloud-ml

I am running my prediction running in CloudML. I want to invoke [predict REST API](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects/predict) from my NodeJS application and I want to show the prediction result in the NodeJS app running in AppEngine.

I can find the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tutorials/python-guide) to do it for Python application. But can't find it for NodeJS.

Can I use normal rest client like [node-rest-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client)? If yes how can I pass the [Google Application Default Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the normal node-rest-client, but since the process for Google Application Default Credentials isn't baked into that client you'll have to use https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs to use Application Default Credentials.

Alternatively you can use the https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client which should support ADC out of the box. You can find the Cloud ML API here:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/src/apis/ml/v1.ts

Specifically, you're looking for the "predict" method.

Comment: But https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client does not have API for CloudML

Comment: Yes it does. I have updated my answer to reflect that.